# Statement about Integral

Tags: calculus, integration

Could you help me with it?
[image]

I tried to change $x =f^{-1}$ (inverse) and do the integration by parts and I'm lost.
How can I see it geometrically?
Do I have to assure that $f$ is continuous and injective? I think yes. But how can I prove it? Can I say it because of the definition of integral?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$f^{-1}$ is well defined since $f$ is monotonic ($f'>0$). We note that this fact plus continuity and the boundary conditions $f(0)=0,\ f(1)=1$ mean that $f$ is bijective on $[0,1]$.

So using the variable change $z:=f^{-1}(x)$ and integration by parts,

\begin{align}
\int_0^1 f(x)\ dx + \int_0^1 f^{-1}(x)\ dx &= \int_0^1 f(x)\ dx + \int_0^1 f^{-1}(f(z))f'(z) \ dz \\
&= \int_0^1 f(x)\ dx + \int_0^1 zf'(z) \ dz \\
&= \int_0^1 f(x)\ dx + zf(z)|^1_0 - \int_0^1 f(z) \ dz \\
&= 1
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Draw a graph of $f$; it is some curve from $(0,0)$ to $(1,1)$ by the conditions you gave. Then the first integral is the area under that curve. Now, $f^{-1}$ is the reflection of the graph through the line $y=x$; what is the second integral? Can you relate that area (geometrically) to an area in the graph of $f$? That should solve your problem. (And yes, you need to convince yourself that $f$ is injective, but that follows from the fact that $f'(x)>0$ on $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 1):

$f'(x)>0$
We consider $f'(x)=a$ where $a>0$
By integrating both side in $[0,1]$ we get
$f(1)-f(0)=a$
We got $f(0)=0$ & $f(1)=1$ from it we get $a=1$
So $f(x)=x$
$y=x$
Or,$f^{(-1)}(y)=y$
Or,$f^{(-1)}(x)=x$ 
From the L.H.S.
By integrating both integrals we will get the answer 1.
L.H.S.= R.H.S.